# How do i access data using two BelongsTo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables - "courses", "lessons" and "tasks". Each lesson belongsTo a course, and each task BelongsTo a lesson. I want to output a task, showing the task name, the lesson name, and the course name. How do I access the course table data? To get the lesson information linked to a course, I have used the following in my Task model:

```
$lessonName = $this->lessons->lesson_name;
```

To get the course name associated to that lesson, I have tried the following with no success, but I am really guessing here:

```
$courseName = $this->lessons->courses->course_name;
```

My model relationships are as follows:

Course.php

```
    public function lessons()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson');
}
```

Lesson.php

```
    public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Task', 'task_id', 'id');
}
```

Task.php

```
    public function lessons()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Lesson', 'lesson_id', 'id');
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is another way you can do this by using accessors.

on your Task model do the following:

```
public function getLessonAttribute(){
    return Lesson::where('id', $this->attributes[*foreign_key_field*])->first();
}
```

Here you receive all the data regarding the lesson that the task belongs to, and can use them as any other attribute (field) of the model.

on your Lesson model get the course that it belongs to.

```
public function getCourseAttribute(){
    return Course::where('id', $this->attributes[*course_foreign_key_field*])->first();
}
```

and then assuming that `$task` is your collection, you can access the lesson and the course like the following in blade:

`$task->lesson->lesson_name` and `$task->lesson->course->course_name`

Answer (score 0):

So you want the inverse of hasManyThrough?

The hasManyThrough feature of Laravel (see their site) facilitates connecting your Courses to Task **directly**, without having the intermediate connection in a separate relationship.

You are looking for the inverse?

Answer (score 0):

In your `lesson.php model` doesn't exist relationship `courses` so there are your issue. Use answer what is told you @jeroenF